# Estilização da label em um input do tipo file

Tags: html, css, input

Existe uma forma de estilizar uma `label` de determinada forma apenas quando o `input` do tipo `file` está com um arquivo selecionado ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei se dá para fazer isso só com css, é preciso rastrear o evento `change` no input, de qualquer maneira aqui está uma solução usando javascript:

```js
function change_label() { // aqui coloca todas as mudanças a acontecer nos elementos que quiser
  var label_file = document.getElementById("label-file");
  label_file.className = "file_on";
  label_file.children[0].innerHTML = 'JÁ EXISTE FICHEIRO';
}
```

```css
.file_on {
 color:red; 
}
```

```html
<label id="label-file" for="file-inp"><span>NÃO EXISTE FICHEIRO</span><br>
  <input onchange="change_label();" id="file-inp" type="file">
</label>
```